# the number of $10$-digit numbers $\overline{a_1 a_2a_3...a_{10}}$ such that $a_i \in \{1,2,3,4\}$ and $\sum_{i=1} ^{i=10} a_i$ is even

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

> Let $n$ be  the number of $10$-digit numbers $\overline{a_1 a_2a_3...a_{10}}$  such that $a_i \in \{1,2,3,4\}$ and $\sum_{i=1} ^{i=10} a_i$ is an even number. Which of following options is true? 
> 1. $n=2^{19}$ 
> 2. $n < 2^{19}-1$
> 3. $n=2^{19}+1$ or $n=2^{19}-1$ 
> 4. $n > 2^{19}+1$

We know for every  $10$-digit numbers  $\overline{a_1 a_2a_3...a_{10}}$  such that $a_i \in \{1,2,3,4\}$ we have $\sum_{i=1} ^{i=10} a_i=2k$, or $2k+1$ so the number of  $10$-digit numbers is $4^{10}=2^{20}$ and half of them are even, so answer is $n=2^{19}$.

Comment: Where is the question?

Answer (score 1):

There are $4^{10}$ numbers with symbols from 1 to 4 and half of them are even. So the result is given by 1.

Comment: How we can solve this if $a_i \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ ?

Comment: A bit different, $5^{10}$ and $2$ out of $5$ are even.

Comment: Seems that the question is misunderstood. It is not asking whether $a_{10}$  is even. Rather it is asking how many of the $10$-digit numbers have  $\sum_{i=1}^{i=10}a_i$ is even.